# how to (if possible) create a SSL certificate for only one website on my apache2 server?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, ssl

I saw some similar posts like this , but it didn't help me at my exact problem.
So I am using ubuntu 12.04 on a server with apache2 on it. There are like 5 websites which are Virtualhosts and Namebased running on it (using the same port). Now I need another page whiche REQUIRES a SSL certificate. 
Is it possible to run just the one page under ssl or do I automatically load everything in it when I configure SSL ?

I know that I have to put the SSL server under Port 443 like this :

```
<virtualhost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your/sslcert
        DocumentRoot /path/your/webcontent
</virtualhost>
```

Does anyone know and want to explain me, how to setup ssl for just one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

first of all check your hostname by entering

```
hostname  (you will need it later)
```

enable ssl-mod

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

guide from scratch :

Create folder for ssl certificate and key

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
```

create .key file and .crt file and after that load both apache2...

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```

when you enter all the details for the certificate make sure that you have the same common name as your hostname , otherwise you will get a warning in your apache2 log for not having the right hostname. (not neccessary, but better to avoid this)

your ssl will only run under port 443 so you need to put the listener 443 to `ports.conf` in your apache dir by adding Listen 443

than create your ssl page under `sites-available`

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl

```
<virtualhost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yourlink
</virtualhost>
```

load the page by `sudo a2ensite ssl`

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

now it will only SSL secure my `yourlink` folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Apache it creates a template for a default virtual host, but it also has a default-ssl virtual host. Copy that file and rename it `my_secure_site` or whatever. Then just change the domain name, the document root, directory, and the ssl key and certificate to the proper values for you site.

Also be sure you have the ssl module enable in Apache `a2enmod mod-ssl`. `ports.conf` should have a statement that will make Apache listen on 443 if a virtual domain is using ssl, but if you have a problem check you are listening on 443.

I had an issue where all my hosts were defined `<virtualhost 123.123.123.132>` and the when I tried to define the ssl site as `<virtualhost 123.123.123.132:443>`. I got an error like the following.

`[Wed Oct 21 16:37:26 2009] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results`

To avoid this all your virtual hosts should explicitly define the port `<virtualhost 123.123.112.132:80>`

Comment: thanks, i just installed certificate and loaded mod and when i now try to reach my page i get an internal error 500 : Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: You might need to add/edit some namevirtualhost directives in ports.conf. The regular namevirtualhost (port 80) should include the Ip and port(80) and inside <if module mod_ssl> directive add (or edit) the namevirtualhost directive to include the Ip and port(443) e.g. 123.123.123.231:443